# Java - Drag and drop not draggable and not working in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

the rehearsed with:

```
    `Point coordinates1 = from.getLocation();
    Point coordinates2 = to.getLocation();  
    TouchActions builder = new TouchActions(driver);
    builder.longPress(coordinates1)
           .move(coordinates2).release(coordinates2).perform();`
```

---

```
    `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    int x2 =to.getLocation().getX();
    int y2 = to.getLocation().getY();
    builder.clickAndHold(from);
    builder.moveByOffset(x2,y2);
    builder.moveToElement(from);
    builder.release();
```

### builder.perform();`

```
    `browser.actions().
    mouseDown(element1).
    mouseMove(x:-1,y:-1).
    mouseMove(element2).
    mouseUp().
```

### perform();`

```
    `Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
    act.moveToElement(to).build().perform();
```

### act.release(to).build().perform();`

```
    `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

### builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release().build().perform();`

```
    `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    from.click();
    builder.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
    builder.moveByOffset(276, 64).build().perform();
    builder.moveToElement(to).build().perform();
```

### builder.release().build().perform();`

`Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

```
     Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from)
                         .moveToElement(to)
                 .release(from)
                 .build();
```

### dragAndDrop.perform();`

`new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();`

Comment: Please edit your question! The code formatting is horrible right now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Point coordinates1 = from.getLocation();
Point coordinates2 = to.getLocation();  
TouchActions builder = new TouchActions(driver);
builder.longPress(coordinates1)
       .move(coordinates2).release(coordinates2).perform();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
int x2 =to.getLocation().getX();
int y2 = to.getLocation().getY();
builder.clickAndHold(from);
builder.moveByOffset(x2,y2);
builder.moveToElement(from);
builder.release();
builder.perform();

browser.actions().
mouseDown(element1).
mouseMove(x:-1,y:-1).
mouseMove(element2).
mouseUp().
perform();

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
act.moveToElement(to).build().perform();
act.release(to).build().perform();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release().build().perform();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
from.click();
builder.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
builder.moveByOffset(276, 64).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(to).build().perform();
builder.release().build().perform();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

 Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from)
                     .moveToElement(to)
                     .release(from)
                     .build();
 dragAndDrop.perform();
```